# How can this C code have lambda

Tags: c, lambda

This code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    void (^a)(void) = ^ void () { printf("test"); } ;
    a();
}
```

Compile without warning with clang -Weverything -pedantic -std=c89 (version clang-800.0.42.1) and print `test`.

I could not find any information about standard C having lambda, also gcc has it's own syntax for lambda and it would be strange for them do this if a standard solution existed.

Comment: Can't reproduce with `clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4` on Ubuntu 16.04. Fails with: `error: blocks support disabled - compile with -fblocks or pick a deployment target that supports them`.

Comment: Blocks are a [clang extension](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html).

Comment: C cannot have this code. Something compiler specific.

Comment: Mmmmh, that smells like Objective-C.

Comment: I **can** reproduce this behavior with `clang-600.0.57` on MAC. the program run without any errors. This might be specfic to a newer clang version.'

Comment: This programming language is _not C_.

Comment: You'd think `-pedantic` with `-std=c89` would at least produce a warning for this non-standard code!

Comment: clang-800.x looks like an Apple version, in which case it probably has extensions useful for OS X enabled by default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior seems to be specfic to newer versions of Clang, and is a [language extension called "blocks"](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html).

The [Wikipedia article on C "blocks"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocks_(C_language_extension)) also provides information which supports this claim:

> Blocks are a non-standard extension added by **Apple Inc. to Clang's implementations of the C, C++, and Objective-C** programming languages that uses a lambda expression-like syntax to create closures within these languages. Blocks are supported for programs developed for Mac OS X 10.6+ and iOS 4.0+, although third-party runtimes allow use on Mac OS X 10.5 and iOS 2.2+ and non-Apple systems.

Emphasis above is mine. On [Clang's language extension page, under the "Block type" section](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/BlockLanguageSpec.html), it gives a brief overview of what the Block type is:

> Like function types, the Block type is a pair consisting of a result value type and a list of parameter types very similar to a function type. Blocks are intended to be used much like functions with the key distinction being that in addition to executable code they also contain various variable bindings to automatic (stack) or managed (heap) memory.

GCC also has something similar to blocks called *lexically scoped nested functions*. However, there are some key differences also note in the Wikipedia articles on C blocks:

> Blocks bear a superficial resemblance to **GCC's extension of C to support lexically scoped nested functions.** However, GCC's nested functions, unlike blocks, must not be called after the containing scope has exited, as that would result in undefined behavior.
>
> GCC-style nested functions also require dynamic creation of executable thunks when taking the address of the nested function. [...].

Emphasis above is mine.

Answer (score 6):

the C standard does not define lambdas at all but the implementations can add extensions.

Gcc also added an extension in order for the programming languages that support lambdas with static scope to be able to convert them easily toward C and compile closures directly.

Here is an example of extension of gcc that implements closures.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int(*mk_counter(int x))(void)
{
    int inside(void) {
        return ++x;
    }
    return inside;
}

int
main() {
    int (*counter)(void)=mk_counter(1);
    int x;
    x=counter();
    x=counter();
    x=counter();
    printf("%d\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code compile with -std=c89 -pedantic, It should not be a language extension

Comment: @mantal Just because clang doesn't report any diagnostics when compiling with `-std=c89 -pedantic` doesn't mean "It should not be a language extension". May be, clang's `-std=c89 -pedantic` doesn't recongize all extensions or the particular version you're using contains a bug. The C standard simply doesn't support lamdas.